# Solid bounded by regions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the region bounded by $x^2+2y^2=2,\space\space z=0,\space\space x+y+2z=2$
>   
> <sub>From *Triple Integrals Multivariable Calculus* - Marsden, Tromba, Weinstein (Springer) 
> Page 316, Excercise 5.4, Problem 10</sub>

My difficulty is in finding the limits of integration without depending on drawing the sketches.

I am taking $$ 0\le z\le \frac{2-x-y}{2}$$
$$ \sqrt{2-2y^2}\le x\le2-y$$
$$ 1\le y\le 2 $$
I'm not sure of the answers either.
 What is an algorithmic approach to finding the limits? 
I'm not able to apply the shadow method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $z$ limits are correct. I will follow an order of integration of $z,y,x$. So, now you have to find the limits of $y$. Notice that its a elliptic cylinder, so the limits of $y$ are:
$$-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}<y<\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$ This covers the whole region of the volume. Symmetrical application in this case is not possible because the plane isn't flat. 
Next is to find the limits of $x$, this might seem to be the most difficult since projecting the solid on the $x\text{-}y$ plane leaves you with an ellipse and a line that are not intersecting. But, our bounds for $x$ are the extremities of the elliptical cylinder which are:
$$-\sqrt{2}<x< \sqrt{2}$$

Final triple integral is:

$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}\int_{0}^{(2-x-y)/2}dz\ dy\ dx$$

It might be helpful to imagine this as a double integral where your integrating the plane, $z=\frac{2-x-y}{2}$ over the region of the ellipse, D:

$$\iint_D \frac{2-x-y}{2}dy \ dx$$

Finally, to imagine how the solid looks like, this is a similar looking solid-though in this case the region is a simple circle.

[image]